# Hardware-assisted virtualization is not present on the server

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I'm trying to configure remote desktop services on a windows server 2012 Hyper-V Virtual Machine and I get the error at the RD virtualization host server.

Hardware-assisted virtualization is not present on the server

is there a way to enable this on the virtual processor?
the VM is running on a Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V Host

Many thanks

Comment: The RD Virtualization Host Role is installed on the host, not in a guest machine.

Comment: I'm trying to turn a VM into an application server hence the need to configure remot desktop services, only when I hit the RD Virtualization host I get this error

Comment: Where did you install the RD Virtualization host role? Again, it needs to go on the Hyper-V host - not on the virtual server you are turning into an application server

Comment: you are absolutely right it makes no sense to install Virtualizatio host on the VM, I rather installed Session host and everything works fine, thanks for the tip REX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *never* virtualize virtual machines. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: well...you can, it's not smart but you can, and you need to pick the right products - for instance you can install ESXi 4/5 in a VMWare Fusion VM on a Mac.

Comment: I corrected my answer to say "shouldn't". Because you really shouldn't. :P

Comment: [TURTLES ALL THE WAY DOWN!](https://twitter.com/DEVOPS_BORAT/status/248770195580125185)

Comment: Times change... These days, ESXi 6.0+, Hyper-V 2016, and KVM all support nested virtualization. Intel processors have had specific CPU features to support it for several generations now. And you know the old saying, "never say never"...

Answer (score 3):

While the answer is technically correct it does not solve the actual problem. The solution for running RDS on Virtual machine is on the "Select deployment Scenario"  to choose "Session based". Then RDS will install on the Virtual Machine. Still need to finish testing but is installed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with either HV or RD, but there is a thing called **nested virtualization** — try looking for that keyword, perhaps you will find some settings in the global Hyper-V configuration.

Comment: If you have to nest virtualization, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: In the context of Windows Remote Desktops — perhaps you are totally right; as I said, I have no expertise on this topic. But nested virtualization in general is an accepted technology.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Not in production environment it's not - for development/test perhaps but anyone doing it for live 'customer' data is creating risk and work for themselves.

Comment: Hyper-V can't currently be nested within a Hyper-V virtual machine.

Comment: Microsoft explicitly says Hyper-V can't *ever* be nested. VMware disagrees, and its latest products are perfectly able to not only virtualize themselves, but virtualize Hyper-V servers too. Of course, this doesn't make any sense outside testing environments.